# How can I render an AppEngine blobstore image on a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: image, html, google-app-engine, canvas

I would like to display an AppEngine blobstore PNG image on an HTML5 canvas. This is what I've tried so far, based on the HTML5 Tutorials and using a webapp template to pass the PNG image and its dimensions to the client:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(png) {
         var ctx = document.getElementById('image').getContext('2d');
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0)
         };
         img.src = png;
      }   
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body onload="draw({{png}});">
 <canvas id="image" width={{width}} height={{height}}></canvas>       
  </body>
</html>
```

The statement

img.src = png

I guess is wrong because the SRC attribute of a JavaScript Image object has to be a server-side filename. But there are no server-side files on the App Engine, so is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Mort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a handler to serve up blobs, [like this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob), then use the URL to that handler in your HTML and javascript. Alternately, since you're serving images, you can serve the image using Google's high performance image serving, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore), and use that URL instead.

Comment: Many thanks, Nick. I should have known, as I'm using a blob server handler already to pass blobs to Picloud.

Answer (score 2):

Images come out of the blobstore using a servlet (or equivalent in python) as a byte array. It's up to you to write code to write that back to the client in a way that they understand. In java it usually looks like this:

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blobkey")); 
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, resp);
```

We use urlRewriteFilter (tuckey.org) to rewrite urls like /image/.png to a call to a servlet /serve?blobKey= so browsers know that they're fetching an image.

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService